# How to register an OLE Server(an exe) as an ActiveX control

Tags: visual-c++, com, activex, ole

I already have an OLE server (a legacy product) in place which can be inserted in MS Office Tool (e.g. Excel) using 'Insert object'. This OLE server is an exe and opens as a window which gets embed when inserted in any MS Office tool.
What should be the process to register this OLE Server as an ActiveX control? This would help me to insert this application as an activeX control in any Windows Form/Office application etc.
 
My knowledge in OLE/ActiveX is primitive. Please let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: I am not an expert but i think in classic vb you can right click in the toolbar and choose the  exe to get embedded into the toolbar, then you can drag it to the form , alternatively you can add them as a reference also i think.

Comment: Hi @sansknwoledge, thanks a lot for the prompt reply. I am not sure about classicVB but have tested MFC by building a Container where we can call 'insert object' to embed the exe. However this is another way to achive but the best one would be if I could add this OLE server as an ActiveX control. Thanks again.